# Capture Audio on PC as a stream in real-time

Tags: c#, naudio

in NAudio you can capture audio using this code

```
capture.Start();
Console.ReadKey();
capture.Stop();
```

but i don't want to wait for `capture.Stop();` i want to access the capture and stream it to another audio device immediately, for example in CsCore you can stream speech synthesis with this code

```
using (var stream1 = new MemoryStream())
     using (var speechEngine1 = new SpeechSynthesizer())
     {
       speechEngine1.SetOutputToWaveStream(stream1);
       speechEngine1.Speak(text_to_read);
       using (var waveOut1 = new CSCore.SoundOut.WaveOut { 
            Device = new WaveOutDevice(audio_device_id) })
            using (var waveSource1 = new MediaFoundationDecoder(stream1))
                 {
                  waveOut1.Initialize(waveSource1);
                  waveOut1.Play();
                  waveOut1.WaitForStopped();
                  }
      }
```

can i do something similar like this code but instead of speech synthesis, i want to stream my default audio device to another audio device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get chunks of bytes by subscribing to an event.
https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/WasapiLoopbackCapture.md

```
capture.DataAvailable += (s, a) =>
{
    writer.Write(a.Buffer, 0, a.BytesRecorded);
    if (writer.Position > capture.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * 20)
    {
        capture.StopRecording();
    }
};
```

Comment: but i'll have to wait until the capture time completes and i don't want that, isn't there any other better way?

Comment: @kurdishdevil event is called as soon as data is available, it does not mean you have to wait until the capture time completes